# Boost enable_if problem

Tags: c++, boost, enable-if

This is more or less copy pasted from boost docs and I keep getting an error (actually alot of errors)

I'm trying to make sure that a template class is only used with numbers using boost.
This is an exercise in boost, rather than making a template class that only uses numbers.

```
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_arithmetic.hpp>

using namespace boost;

template <class T>
class A<T, typename enable_if<is_arithmetic<T> >::type> // <-- this is line 9
{
    int foo;
};

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

The first few errors
C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<' : line 9
C2059: syntax error : '<' : line 9
C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration

Visual Studio 2005 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually created a class template called `A`.  You just created a *specialization*.  You need to first create the `A` class template with a dummy parameter for the enabler to work.

```
using namespace boost;

template <class T, class Enable = void>
class A { };

template <class T>
class A<T, typename enable_if<is_arithmetic<T> >::type> 
{
    int foo;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Before specializing the `A` class template you would have to at least declare it.

A solution depends on what you're trying to achieve, because the problem you're asking for help about is an attempted solution to some problem.

The [Boost documentation](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html#htoc6) of `enable_if` has this example, which perhaps is what you want:

```
template <class T, class Enable = void> 
class A { ... };

template <class T>
class A<T, typename enable_if<is_integral<T> >::type> { ... };

template <class T>
class A<T, typename enable_if<is_float<T> >::type> { ... };
```

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are missing the `::type` at the end. Enable_if construct can be error prone sometimes. I use this little macro to make it easier:

```
#define CLASS_REQUIRES(...) typename boost::enable_if<boost::mpl::and_<__VA_ARGS__, boost::mpl::bool_<true> > >::type
```

Then you can write the above code like this:

```
template <class T, class Enable = CLASS_REQUIRES(is_arithmetic<T>)>
class A 
{
    int foo;
};
```

Its a lot easier on the eyes.