# Compilation error: boost is_complex in if

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits

I have a question related to the boost function is_complex.

I have the following (simplified) template function:

```
template< typename T>
void foo(T x) {
   if(boost::is_complex<T>::value) {
      bar( std::real(x) );
   } else {
      bar(x);
   }
}
```

T is either a numerical type (int, double, etc.) or std::complex with U being a numerical type as well. Unfortunately the above function won't compile because bar can only handle numerical values. That's the reason why I am using the if-condition but the compiler only sees that I want to call bar with a complex type which is not defined.

How can I fix this? I guess it is a rather common question with type traits, but I couldn't find something similar. Probably because I don't really know which keywords I should search for...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please.

Comment: The most probable reason for your problem is that both branches of the `if() {} else {}` are evaluated at compile time. You'll rather need something like `std::enable_if()` to do that using SFINAE.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068286/boost-enable-if-problem

Comment: Instead of enable_if you could also use *if constexpr* from C++17 to evaluate an expression at compile time.